# I want to use crypto.hash inside the chainlink functions

Tags: function, import, require, chainlink

I want to use the crypto package to use the `crypto.getRandomNumbers` and `crypto.createHash()` inside the source.js in the 1-simple-computation of the chainlink functions.
This is my code :

```js
// calculate geometric mean off-chain by a DON then return the result
// valures provided in args array4
//console.log(`calculate geometric mean of ${args}`)/
// args = getRandomJeton();

const crypto = require("crypto");
function getRandomJeton(Choix_Vote, N_V) {
  // Avoir deux nombre completement aleatoire
  let randomAnonymeNumber1 = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0];
  let randomAnonymeNumber2 = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0];
  // Avoir un nombre unique a chaque citoyen
  let uniqueNumber = "12345678910";
  // Mettre ensemble le nombre aleatoire et unique pour cree un nombre 100% aleatoire et unique
  let uniqueRandomValue = `${uniqueNumber}${randomAnonymeNumber2}${randomAnonymeNumber1}`;
  // Mettre ensemble les donne necessaire pour avoir le jeton
  let unhashedJeton = `${Choix_Vote}${uniqueRandomValue}${N_V}`;
  const Jeton = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(unhashedJeton).digest("hex");
  return Jeton;
}
const Jeton = getRandomJeton();
return Jeton;
```

I know that in the documentation it is written that i cannot use modules. But I really need a secure way to get 100% randomNumbers (not with math.random) and I need to get a hash function as well. Is there anyway around this? I would really appricate the help :)
Thank you for taking your time.

When I use crypto `const crypto = require("crypto")` , I can call the request.js, but it will not give me a response and get me the error `❌ Error during simulation:  require is not defined`. So I tried to use the import statement as such `import crypto from "crypto"` but i get that this error trying to  `node source.js`   `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` .

Answer (score 0):

With Functions, at the moment, you can use vanilla JavaScript only.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, is there any functions in vanilla JavaScript that I can use in this case scenario to hash my message ? Alternatively, would it be possible to import a value from anotehr javascript file, that allows the crypto functions, in my source.js so that the source.js file only has to recover a final value ?